# Bar Button Item not working after dismissing UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a Bar Button Item that triggers an alert that asks the user whether they want to take a photo or pick an image from their library. Upon picking photo library, I instantiate a UIImagePickerController so they select a photo.

My problem is that after picking an image and dismissing the view controller, the app returns to the original view controller, image is displayed in the outlet properly, but the button that worked before will not trigger the alert to select an image again (nor will anything print to console).

```
@IBAction func pickAnImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    selectImageSourceAlert()
}

func selectImageSourceAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    let userLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .Default) {
        _ in
        self.presentImagePicker(pickerStyle: .PhotoLibrary)
    }
    let useCamera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .Default) {
        _ in
        let x = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera)
        print(x)
        if x {
            self.presentImagePicker(pickerStyle: .Camera)
        } else {
            print("No camera available")
        }
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(userLibrary)
    alert.addAction(useCamera)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func presentImagePicker(pickerStyle style: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = style
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        imagePickerView.image = image
    }
}
```

After a few days I'm still not able to figure it out. I have found that when I remove the "if let image = info" bit, and forgo assigning the image to the imagePickerView outlet, the button works after dismissing the view controller. The button also works if I cancel at any point before selecting an image. It only doesn't work when I assign the image to the outlet.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: I've noticed when I added a second button in the upper right corner and assigned it to the same action, it works even after assigning a photo. The first Bar Button Item in the bottom left corner will only work while there is no image assigned to the imageView. Not sure why as it isn't covered by the imageView in any way. Added red background color for clarity.

[Simulation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihFAf.png)

Comment: Please show us the code for the button that triggers the Image Picker.

Comment: Just added the additional code to the original post. It's a bit long but hopefully it helps.

Comment: I have just tried your code in a new project and it works okay in my case.
What are you doing with the selected image after dismissing image picker?

Comment: Nothing, I go back to the original View Controller and I try to select the button again but it won't trigger an action. Its puzzling me how it works the first time, but it won't trigger a s second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After selecting image, your ToolBar has 0 height.
You can see this in "Debug view hierarchy".

To fix this just remove constraint "Toolbar.top = Image Picker View.bottom + 192"

Comment: Strange how the toolbar is removed but the bar button item still displays. But this did it for me! Thank you Damian!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

You really don't need this as the Image Picker has been closed.
This function will dismiss the current view controller.

Also, try to use dispatch_async when updating a UI object.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
{
  if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage 
  {
     self.imagePickerView.image = image
  }
})
```

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks for the input. I went ahead and updated my original question with further details and an image. Hopefully this helps. I think I'm missing something incredibly simple, but can't see it for the life of me.

Comment: Hi Eman, is that all the code you are using? It seems like we are missing something here?

Comment: It definitely has to do with my UIBarButtonItem. Maybe a storyboard issue? Here's a link to the github project, maybe you can catch something in the storyboard? [git](https://github.com/emanleet/Meme-Me)